# Removing items from list by index while looping through list

Tags: java, list

```
public boolean isTwoPair() {
    boolean isTwoPair = false;
    Collections.sort(deck);
    List<Card> cards = new LinkedList<Card>(deck);
    System.out.println(cards);  
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < cards.size()-1; j++) {
            if (deck.get(i).equals(deck.get(j))) {
                cards.remove(i);
                cards.remove(j);
                System.out.println(cards);
            }
        }

    }
    return isTwoPair;

}
```

I think my problem is with my cards.remove(). When I remove a card, the next time the card is removed it removes it from an altered list. Is there a way to remove two items from a list while they have the same index numbers?

If I have to remove index 0,1 because they are both pairs like so:

```
[Ace,Ace,Three,Four,Four]
```

the code removes it like this(removing index 0)

```
[Ace,Three,Four,Four]
```

than instead of removing the index 1(Ace) from the first list it removes it from the second list so

```
[Ace,Four,Four]
```

It removed the index 1 from the second list which was three.

This is what I was expecting

```
[Three,Four,Four]
```

At this point I expect my loop to pick up and remove Four and Four

EDIT:

```
    public boolean isTwoPair() {
    boolean isTwoPair = false;
    Collections.sort(deck);
    List<Card> cards = new LinkedList<Card>(deck);
    System.out.println(cards);  
    for (int cardOne = 0; cardOne < cards.size(); cardOne++) {
        for (int cardTwo = cardOne + 1; cardTwo < cards.size(); cardTwo++) {
            if (deck.get(cardOne).equals(deck.get(cardTwo))) {
                cards.remove(cardOne);
                cards.remove(cardTwo-1);
                System.out.println(cards);
                for(int cardThree = 0; cardThree < cards.size(); cardThree++){
                    for(int cardFour = cardThree+1; cardFour < cards.size(); cardFour++){
                        if(cards.get(cardThree).equals(cards.get(cardFour))){
                            cards.remove(cardThree);
                            cards.remove(cardFour-1);
                            System.out.println(cards);
                            isTwoPair = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return isTwoPair;

}
```

this is what I am using now, I didn't really want to make a new variable if I didn't have to so I decided to not remove Object

Comment: don't remove Aces, just save somewhere the fact that they form a pair.

Comment: Another option is to replace items with `null`, and ignore `null` items.

Comment: I actually tried something like setting an arrays index to null but it gave me an error right away, how do I ignore nulls?

Comment: @droidbehavior You just only process things that aren't null... `if (deck.get(cardOne) != null) { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know `j` is always greater than `i` (because of the for loop), if you delete the element with index `i` first then you can delete the element with index `j - 1` getting the expected result.

```
cards.remove(i);
cards.remove(j-1);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to loop from `i = 0` to `< cards.size()-1` Because then you are missing one card, try `i < cards.size()`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`List.remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of `List.remove(int)`. That will not depend on the ordering of the List anymore.

```
public boolean isTwoPair() {
    boolean isTwoPair = false;
    Collections.sort(deck);
    List<Card> cards = new LinkedList<Card>(deck);
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < cards.size()-1; j++) {
            cardI = deck.get(i);
            cardJ = deck.get(j);
            if (cardI.equals(cardJ)) {
                cards.remove(cardI);
                cards.remove(cardJ);
                isTwoPair = true;
            }
        }

    }
    return isTwoPair;

}
```

Comment: thanks this worked, I didn't know there was an option to remove object

Answer (score 1):

```
cards.remove(i);
cards.remove(j);
```

As soon as you remove an element from the `LinkedList`, it shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). You could use `j-1` instead of `j` if `j > i`. Or, `cards.remove(Card)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you remove an object from the list you are not accounting for the fact that the size is not the same after removal and that indices of elements are changed after removal

Suppose you want to remove elements at and 0 and 1

```
initially => [Ace,Ace,Three,Four,Four]
               0   1    2     3    4
```

remove [0]

```
after removing [0] => [Ace,Three,Four,Four]
                        0    1     2    3
```

remove [1]

```
after removing [1] => [Ace,Four,Four]
                        0   1     2
```

Thus you cant us indices for removal, instead use `List.remove(Object)`