# Why is a temp variable not the same as what I get from arraylist.get?

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a problem where I have to find the first non repeating character of a string. I know my solution is weird or inefficient but one thing that isn't making sense is that when I set

```
char temp = check.get(i);
```

the variable in `temp` doesn't seem to be the same thing

```
public static Character firstNonRepeatedCharacter(String str)
{
    ArrayList<Character> check = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        check.add(c);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < check.size(); i++) {
        char temp = check.get(i);
        check.remove(check.get(i));

        if (check.contains(temp)) {
            check.removeAll(Collections.singleton(temp));
        } else {
            return temp;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think they're not the same?

Comment: @SeanBright - The "first non-repeating character" of a string is the "earliest" character in the string that doesn't appear again "later" in the string

Comment: Not sure if you've considered this, but each time through your loop you are both incrementing the index variable, and removing an item from the array, so you're are going to be skipping things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing items from list by index while looping through list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113721/removing-items-from-list-by-index-while-looping-through-list)

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that once you remove some item from the ArrayList, e.g.

```
check.remove(check.get(i));
```

all the items in the ArrayList get "moved up": if you remove the item at index 5, the item that used to be at index 6 is now at index 5.  When you then go to remove the item at (new) index 6, you removing the one that was at the (original) index 7.

Answer (score 0):

^^ What Dan said above. Another error you'd be running into is if you keep having no characters that are non repeating. The

> check.size()

keeps updating for every time you remove repeating characters. If you're not able to find a non repeating character fast enough, the index i will exceed that of check.size(), exiting the for loop even though there may be a non repeating character left in the string!
To remedy this, I would simply use a while loop instead.